# Get dynamic tableview cell height and autorelease

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to set dynamic table view cell height like this. Inside layoutSubviews, it will set cellHeight.

My question is that if we create cell like that (may be for 100 rows), are those cell automatically released? Or will it still be on memory?

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (tableView == self.tblInspiration)
    {
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
            TitleCell* cell = (TitleCell*)[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            [cell layoutSubviews]; 
            float height = cell.cellHeight;
            cell = nil; 
            return height;
        }

    }
 }
```

If I dun use that and I only return constant height (e.g 100), memory usage is 25. If I use, it is about 40 and never reduce back also. That means there is memory usage. Is it correct? What is the best way to do?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes those cell automatically released.

The better way is

```
float cellHeight = cell.cellHeight;
cell = nil;
return cellHeight;
```

Comment: I have used your method and still it is not reduced. If i just return constant (e.g 100), it is reduced.

Comment: yes it is reduced the line but what you want to reduced?

Comment: oh i mean memory usage is not reduced if i also use your suggestion. May I know how to do

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in  `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will try to reuse already created cells if there are any fitted for the current situation, if not the table view will create new cells, this new cells will never be used but they still use memory, that's why your memory don't decrease.

I suggest that you create a member variable for your  `TitleCell` and `alloc` it one time and use the same cell in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` (set the proper values on it and compute the height).

Comment: I am not sure what u mean. If we use TitleCell and alloc one time only, it will still create new one in heightForRowAtIndexPath. Sharing cell between heightForRowAtIndexPath and cellForRowAtIndexPath is required. Is it correct? If possible, can you explain with code? (pseudocode also okay).

Comment: @KhantThuLinn You'll only alloc one cell one time only, in your current implementation you'll alloc one cell for every row (visible rows). Also, you'll have to know that `heightForRow` is called for all the rows before `cellForRow` is called.